# Vue глобальная регистрация компонентов

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue3

Приложение собрано через init vue@latest, кое-что не понимаю.
Как правильно глобально регистрировать компоненты?

Есть следующий компонент:

```
<template>
  <header class="nav container-fluid pt-3">
    <h1 class="title">CCJ Music</h1>
    <h2>Charts</h2>
    <h2>Albums</h2>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MainHeader'
}
</script>
```

Он импортирован в
js файле который находится в корневой папке с компонентами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Туда так же попадут остальные компоненты и буду экспортированы как массив

```
import MainHeader from '@/components/UI/hard/mh.vue'

export default [
    MainHeader,
]
```

В main.js регистрирую все компоненты:

```
import components from '@/components/UI/library.js';

const app = createApp(App)

components.forEach(component => {
    app.component(component.name, component)
})
```

Все правильно регистрирует, но почему то при использовании его в экземпляре он не работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот экземпляр:

```
<template>

  <MainHeader></MainHeader>

</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {
    // когда регистрирую его тут, он не может его найти https://i.gyazo.com/bb84ef3ac0719c0d7155411debde9612.png
  }
}
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@200;400&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Не понятно, зачем вы так делаете.. В компоненте просто подключайте нужный вам компонент и регистрируйте.. `import { defineComponent } from 'vue' `

Comment: Ну вью дает такую возможность, почему бы и нет, тем более если их будет много..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка связана с тем, что вы ожидаете компонент по имени тега `<MainHeader>` (CamelCase), а `Vue` ожидает название в kebab-case:

```
MainHeader -> main-header
```

Это связано с тем, что браузер приводит все теги и атрибуты к нижнему регистру и когда `vue` приступает к синтаксическому анализу DOM, в нем ваш тег `MainHeader` будет приведен к виду `mainheader` и соответственно не будет разрешен `Vue`. [Предостережения при синтаксическом анализе шаблона DOM](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats)

Чтобы избежать подобных проблем, вам следует запомнить одно правило по поводу именования компонентов (атрибутов, тегов):

> в HTML = kebab-case, в JavaScript = СamelCase

Пример (обратите внимание, в стартовом html блоке используется `<main-header>` (kebab-case), а в `template` компонента `MainHeader` используется `<MainComponent>` (CamelCase)

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;


const MainHeader = {
  name: 'MainHeader',
  template: `
    <header class="nav container-fluid pt-3">
    <h1 class="title">CCJ Music</h1>
    <h2>Charts</h2>
    <h2>Albums</h2>
   
      <MainComponent />
  </header>
  `
}

const MainComponent = {
  name: 'MainComponent',
  template: `
    <footer>
      MainComponent
    </footer>
  `
}
const components = [
  MainHeader,
  MainComponent,
]

const app = createApp()

components.forEach(component => {
  app.component(component.name, component)
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <main-header></main-header>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, такой вопрос, когда мы уже глобально компоненты зарегистрировали, почему в родительском апп я не могу просто зарегистрировать компонент, мне нужно его еще и импортировать.

Comment: Если вы зарегистрировали компонент глобально, то его уже не нужно подключать или импортировать где-либо, он будет доступен в любом действующем компоненте вашего приложения

Comment: Внутри папки UI я могу использовать компоненты без импортов, но к примеру в views - нет
https://i.gyazo.com/1cc291236e57006ce307eb1b9e361307.png
https://github.com/mirikking/vue-music-app/tree/music-app

Comment: Как я и написал вам выше, удаляете все импорты тех компонентов, которые у вас заявлены как глобальные и все работает при соблюдении рекомендаций, которые я привел вам в ответе. Вот ваш код в работе - https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-framework-yy6g3t - я закомментировал все импорты в `views`

Comment: Я даже и не знаю как благодарность выразить..
Спасибо огромное )

Comment: Если вам ответ помог, можете принять его и +1

Comment: не могу +1 тыкнуть :(